# The problem of tag in align environmnt

Tags: align, alignment, tags

Normally, tag is only used in labeling. However, I want to use tag to text something longer than labels.

Image:

[image]

WMF:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Here I want, 
\begin{align}
    \sqrt{\smash[b]{1-x^2}}+\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y^2}}=C\,\,(0<C<2). \notag
    \\[-17pt]
    \tag*{$(\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-x^2}}\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y^2}}\ne 0000000000000000000)$}
\end{align} 
However, I can only do this,
\begin{align}
    \sqrt{\smash[b]{1-x^2}}+\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y^2}}=C\,\,(0<C<2). 
    \tag*{$(\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-x^2}}\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y^2}}\ne 0000000000000000000)$}
\end{align} 
This is not centered.
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{\smash[b]{1-x^2}}+\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y^2}}=C\,\,(0<C<2)\text{．}
    \hfill(\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-x^2}}\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y^2}}\ne 0).
\end{align*}
Here hfill doesn't work.
\end{document}
```

Does it exist other ways to achieve the effect like the first formula? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: `left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm` may be expressed more succinctly as `margin=1cm`.

Comment: Have edited, thx :)

Comment: Don't abuse `\tag` for this: the condition is *part of the equation*, not a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't abuse `\tag` for setting conditions that are part of the equation.

If you really want the condition at the right margin (but you shouldn't), you can use `flalign` and manually add some space to the right.

Alternatively, and preferable, don't push the condition and use some judgment in adding some horizontal space to get “almost centering”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' environment
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \cramped

\begin{document}

First way, which I'd prefer
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\hspace{4em}
& \sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-\smash[b]{\cramped{y^2}}}=C \quad (0<C<2). 
&\qquad&
\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-\smash[b]{\cramped{y^2}}}\ne 0.00000000000000000) \\
&\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-\smash[b]{\cramped{y^2}}}=C \quad (0<C<2). 
\end{alignat*}

Second way, which I dislike
\begin{flalign*}
&\hspace{6em}&&
\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-\smash[b]{\cramped{y^2}}}=C \quad (0<C<2). 
&&\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-\smash[b]{\cramped{y^2}}}\ne 0.00000000000000000) \\
&&&
\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-\smash[b]{\cramped{y^2}}}=C \quad (0<C<2). 
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how I got cramped style for the exponents under the square root.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you encase the argument of `\tag*` in an `\llap` directive.

[image]

The contents of the second line of the `gather*` environment are centered horizontally by construction. A comparison of the contents of lines 1 and 2 demonstrates that the contents of line 1 -- other than the lengthy tag... -- are also centered horitzontally. Thus, the OP's formatting objective is met.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' environment

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-x^2}}+\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y^2}}=C \quad (0<C<2). 
\tag*{\llap{($\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-x^2}}\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y^2}}\ne 0.00000000000000000$})} \\
\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-x^2}}+\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y^2}}=C \quad (0<C<2). 
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will center the equation, but I had to reduce the margins to get it to fit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Here I want, 
\begin{flalign*}
  \phantom{(\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-x^2}}\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y^2}}\ne 0000000000000000000)} &&
    \sqrt{\smash[b]{1-x^2}}+\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y^2}}=C\,\,(0<C<2). &&
    (\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-x^2}}\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y^2}}\ne 0000000000000000000)
\end{flalign*} 
\end{document}
```